# Rendering breaks when using an int in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm rendering light spheres for a deferred renderer and I'm in the process of switching to instancing for better performance. I have the following vertex shader:

```c
in vec3 position;

uniform int test_index;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix[256];

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix[test_index] * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

I upload the matrices to the shader with

```
val location = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "modelMatrix[$i]")
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, false, buf)
```

When I use the `int` uniform in the index (Hardcoded to a `0` for debugging purposes), the sphere disappears, except when I clip into geometry (in which case it renders as a white circle). The same happens when I use `gl_InstanceID` as my index.

Weirdly I noticed that the problem also occurs when I pass an `int` from vertex to fragment shader and use it there for something completely different, regardless of what I use as the index.

[image: glitch]

The problem disappears instantly and rendering is completely fine when I hardcode `modelMatrix[0]` in the shader instead of `modelMatrix[test_index]`.

I've got a different shader (for skeletal animation) which uploads a mat4 uniform array the exact same way, also being indexed with an int, but I've got no such problems there...

I don't really know what to make of this, so any advice on how I can debug this is much appreciated. I'm using OpenGL 3.3 on Kotlin+LWJGL

Edit: This probably has nothing to do with the uniform. The following also does *not* work:

```
int i = 0;
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix[i] * vec4(position, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I'd attach a debugger and confirm that the value of that uniform in the shader is indeed 0. Also note that if you hardcode it to `modelMatrix[0]`, you're removing the use of `test_index`, and so it will effectively disappear from the shader, removed by the optimizer. You might want to try forcing the use of this variable, and then passing an explicit zero to see if it's an issue with its existence or its value.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz For testing, I used the `text_index` as the W coordinate of my vector, like this: `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix[0] * vec4(position, float(test_index));` - Works fine, and when I hardcode the uniform to 1, it will show up normally. So it's not its existence.

Comment: Random guess: When you hardcode `modelMatrix[0]`, then the compiler optimizes away `modelMatrx[1]` to `modelMatrix[255]`. But if it's not hardcoded, then it will have to keep them. 256 matrix uniforms is probably more than a shader supports. Try to reduce the size of the matrix array to something reasonable (let's say 10) and see if it works.

Comment: @BDL Yup, that's it. Works with an array size of 16 and even 128. Thank you! I guess for more data, I'd need a buffer of some kind?

Comment: It now works for the matrices, but passing an int from vertex to fragment shader still breaks it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL has a limit on how many uniforms one can use. The same applies to attributes too (but that's not the problem here). An array of 256 matrices is very likely to exceed the allowed amount.

The reason why the code only breaks when using the int uniform is that glsl compilers do a lot of optimization under the hood, for example, removing unused uniforms. So if you hardcode the array location in the shader, the compiler will notice that only a single matrix is ever used and might remove all the others.

When you need more uniforms than what OpenGL allows for, you have to use a uniform buffer object (UBO) or a shader storage buffer (SSBO).